# JQuery table not interpreting the values , getting only one character

Tags: jquery-ui, jquery, datatable, datatables

Jquery datatable is not interpreted the jsonarray values.I'm getting only one character in the table.,

```
<table border="1" cellspacing="0" cellpadding="0" id="products" style="clear:both;">
    <thead>
        <tr>
            <th>Product</th>
            <th>Description</th>
        </tr>
                     </thead>
      <tbody>
      </tbody>
     </table>
```

Actual data format coming from server:

```
["Element software","Software dist","Global envir","Software","Software list"]
```

jquery Datatable code:

```
 var oTable = $("#products").dataTable({
        "aaData" : data,
        "bProcessing" : true,
        "sPaginationType" : "full_numbers",
        "bJQueryUI" : true,
        "bRetrieve" : true,
        "bPaginate" : true,
        "bStateSave" : true,
        "bSort" : true,
        "aaSorting" : [[ 4, "desc" ]],
        "iDisplayLength" : 25,
        "oLanguage": {
        "sProcessing": "processing",
        "sEmptyTable": "No records found."
        }

        });
```

Action class:

```
     JSONArray ja = new JSONArray();
    try {
         Iterator it = List.iterator();
         while(it.hasNext()){
             SearchResult part = (SearchResult) it.next();
         ja.add(part.getlist1());
         ja.add(part.getlist2());
         findList.addAll(ja);
         }
```

returning findList which is arraylist.

How to interpret the data to datatable ?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

If you have 2 columns in your table you need an array of 2 element arrays as your data input:

```
[["Element software", "descr1"], ["Software dist", "descr2"],
["Global envir", "descr3"], ["Software", "descr4"], ["Software list", "descr5"]]
```